# ng-repeat with $scope's integer value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-repeat on an integer value which is shared in $scope.
My code is-

Html-

```
<div ng-repeat="t in getTimes({{selected.head.numberOfHead}}) track by 
     $index">{{$index}
</div>
```

js-

```
  $scope.getTimes=function(n){
            return new Array(n);
  }
```

Here, `{{selected.head.numberOfHead}}` argument in `getTimes()` is not working. How can I do that???

If I use getTimes`({{selected.head.numberOfHead}})`

**Error:**
 `

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 11 of the expression [getTimes({{selected.head.numberOfHead}})]` starting at [{selected.head.numberOfHead}})].
```

If I use `getTimes('{{selected.head.numberOfHead}}')`-
Its not looping

If I use `getTimes({{'selected.head.numberOfHead'}})`

**Error:**

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 11 of the expression [getTimes({{'selected.head.numberOfHead'}})] starting at [{'selected.head.numberOfHead'}})].
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working"? Do you have an error in the Javascript console you can share?

Comment: have been clarified

Comment: try to remove the {{ }}

Comment: +1 to @AmrMagdy. Also, (in general) try googling your error; first result for "Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 11 of the expression" for me was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357055/having-a-hard-time-debugging-error-token-invalid-key-at-column-2/31357878

Comment: also you have to replace {{$index} with {{$index}}

Comment: check this fiddle for more info http://jsfiddle.net/L2hqzshb/. there are many thins wrong as suggested by other people in comments.