# How to do an if-else using ngClass?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-class

I am using AngularJS on my site, and have a widget displayed on one of my webpages, and want to change the `style` element of some text displayed in a `div` tag depending on whether a boolean value associated with that text is true or false.

An alarm is raised on the web page, and displayed in the widget when an integer variable reaches a certain limit (i.e. when x >= 100, the `alarmRaised` boolean is set to true). The value of the variable is always displayed on the page, and is being updated every 30 seconds.

When the alarm is raised, a warning is raised (and displayed on a separate page)- the user has the option to accept that warning. When the warning has been accepted, I want the text showing the value of the variable to be displayed in one colour, and when it hasn't, I want to display it in another colour.

The HTML where this 'alarm' text is displayed is inside one of the JS functions for that page:

```
.directive('tagBox', function($timeout, tag, colourFilter){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ...
        },
        template: ...
            ...
            '<div data-ng-repeat="alarm in alarms" data-ng-class="{\'text-warning\':alarm.accepted.value, \'text-danger\':!alarm.accepted.value}">{{alarm.message.value}}</div>'
```

Inside the above `<div></div>` tag, I want to use some in-line JS to say: "if the value of `alarm.accepted.value` is true, display the value of `alarm.message.value` in one colour; if it's false, display it in another colour... How would I do this?

Comment: [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)? `condition ? value-when-true : value-when-false`

Comment: You could add color to your text-warning and text-danger classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ngClass in your template, you may want to use the ternary operator in [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
<div ng-class="alarm.accepted.value ? 'text-warning' : 'text-danger'">
    ...
</div>
```

Note that it works since Angular 1.1.4. If you are using Angular 1.1.1, ternary operator is not supported. You can use instead:

```
<div ng-class="{'text-warning': alarm.accepted.value, 'text-danger': !alarm.accepted.value}">
    ...
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div ng-class="{true:'text-warning', false:'text-danger'}[alarm.accepted.value]">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: @someone2088 Be careful there are no `{}` in the ternary's synthax. [*Related issue **here***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31357878/4927984)

Comment: @someone2088 You have to escape some `'` in your string: `'<div data-ng-class="alarm.accepted.value ? \'text-warning\' : \'text-danger\'">'`

Comment: you can use this jsfiddler to see a working example,  https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1418/

Comment: Ah my bad- I've only just taken this project on, and it seems the reason I couldn't get it working as you had suggested was because I had referenced the wrong variable elsewhere... Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ternary operator to achieve this.

`.." + (alarm.accepted.value ? "text-warning" : "text-danger") + "...`